# How can I force all URI requests to index.php?

Tags: php, laravel, apache, cakephp-routing

In my `index.php` (which is in my project root directory) I have a basic routing system that grabs the url (using `$_SERVER[‘REQUEST_URI]`) and calls the proper ‘controller’ which then calls the proper ‘view’ (so, implementation of very basic MVC). What I have in my `index.php` looks like this:

```
$router= Router::load('Routes.php');
$uri=trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/'); 
require $router->direct($uri);
```

Problem is, I can not seem to make all requests go to `index.php`. 
Obviously if you go to `localhost/myproject/` you will get to `index.php` (therefore the proper controller will be called), however what I want is that even if you type `localhost/myproject/contact` to first be direct to `index.php`. So that `index.php` can handle routing for you.

Comment: Check any MVC framework for the standard approach, eg [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/installation#pretty-urls), [Codeigniter](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html#removing-the-index-php-file) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using apache you can use `.htaccess` file to redirect every request in your `index.php` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/index\.php$ - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

If you are using nginx server you can redirect all request to `index.php` file with this code in your `.conf` file:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Do I add the .htaccess file to my localhost root directory (localhost) or to 'my project' root folder, in this case (localhost/myproject/) ?

Comment: Yes, if you are using apache you have to put .htaccess in your root directory